# Prayer while bathing

Tags: tefilla, tznius-modesty, showering-bathing

Is there anything that would prevent praying while showering/bathing? If so, what is the Torah principle behind the reasoning? For example, is it a question of modesty?

Comment: Do you mean prayer as in the Shimonei Esrei? Or as in "Please G-d don't let me slip in the shower"?

Comment: @יהושעק I'm wondering about prayer in general.

Comment: Have you considered [accepting my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Answer (score 2):

The [Orach Chayim 85:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%94_%D7%91) forbids saying the Shema in a bathhouse, and the Rema extends this ban even on learning the *halakhot* of a bathhouse (see also [Berakhot 24b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.24b.16), [Mishnei Torah Keriat Shema 3:4](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912954/jewish/Kriat-Shema-Chapter-Three.htm#v4)). You are not allowed either to say the Shema or blessings while your sensitive parts are not covered ([Berakhot 25b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.25b.11), [Orach Chayim 74](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%93), [Mishnei Torah Keriat Shema 3:16–17](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912954/jewish/Kriat-Shema-Chapter-Three.htm#v16)), so I don't think that there is a way to pray while bathing. The only exception is the case of a murky mikveh, where the water is not transparent and your full body (except your head) is covered with the water ([Berakhot 25b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.25b.4), [Orach Chayim 74:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%93_%D7%91)). The scriptural basis of these modesty rules are from [Devarim 23:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.23.15):

> כִּי֩ יְהוָ֨ה אֱלֹהֶ֜יךָ מִתְהַלֵּ֣ךְ ׀ בְּקֶ֣רֶב מַחֲנֶ֗ךָ לְהַצִּֽילְךָ֙ וְלָתֵ֤ת אֹיְבֶ֙יךָ֙ לְפָנֶ֔יךָ וְהָיָ֥ה מַחֲנֶ֖יךָ קָד֑וֹשׁ **וְלֹֽא־יִרְאֶ֤ה בְךָ֙ עֶרְוַ֣ת דָּבָ֔ר** וְשָׁ֖ב מֵאַחֲרֶֽיךָ׃
>
> For *Hashem* thy God walketh in the midst of thy camp, to deliver thee, and to give up thine enemies before thee; therefore shall thy camp be holy; **that He see no unseemly thing in thee,** and turn away from thee.

Comment: There are opinions that modern bathrooms are clean enough that this doesn't apply. I wonder if any of those opinions are legitimately held nowadays (as far as I know, everyone holds that we can't even think Torah thoughts in a bathroom, even if clean). A bath with bubbles might be the perfect place to catch up on a bit of learning!

Comment: Thinking and speaking are different in this regard and it's worth clarifying which are allowed where

Comment: @DoubleAA indeed, I am thinking of turning it into a question but first I want to try and catch up on those sources.